# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int'

Tags: c

The code below is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Anyone have any clues as to why?

The following warnings are reported:

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int'

```
register int t;
char *s;
double val;

s = printn(val);
t = strlen(s); // <<< breaks on this line

...

char *printn(n)
double n;
{
    register char *fmt, *s, *ss;
    double absn;
    short sign;

    ....
    s = printb("%-0.2f", sign*absn);
    for (ss = s; *ss; ++ss);
    while (*--ss == '0' || *ss == ' ') *ss = 0;
    if (*ss == '.') *ss = 0;

    return(s);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `register`? K&R-style function definitions? Is it 1982 again?

Comment: Close!  This code is actually from 1983

Comment: Ah, in 1983, there was a good chance of `sizeof(char*) == sizeof(int)`. Under that condition, the code has a not too bad chance of working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *s;
double val;

s = printn(val);
```

At this point, no declaration of `printn` is in scope. So the compiler, using the old C89 rules, assumes an implcit declaration of `printn` returning an `int`.

Declare all functions before you use them.

```
char *printn(double n);
char *s;
double val;
// ..
s = printn(val);
```

That would work.

```
char *printn(n)
double n;
{
```

Please use the modern syntax,

```
char * printn(double n)
{
    // implementation
```